# Request $request convert to Array $data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at laravel and i was reading the document for a week now. i was working on crud about modification of register form i'm almost finish but then i bump in to this problem which is now i'm trying to look for a right syntax on my question would be how to i check and move a file use as a parameter  to store and create a path folder for the image. similar to the code below i show using Request. cause if you look at the register page controller at the create function the parameter used is array.

tried reading documents and research couldn't find any or maybe i lack of keywords to direct me into this type of problem.

I have this code and this is right

```
public function store(Request $Request) 
{
    $ProfileUser = new User();

    if($Request->hasfile('Img1'))
    {
        $file = $Request->file('Img1');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Get Image Ext.
        $filename = time() . "." . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/employee/', $filename);
        $ProfileUser->image1 = $filename;
    } else 
    {
        return $Request;
        $ProfileUser->image1 = 'no image';
    }

    $ProfileUser->fname = $Request->input('fname');
    $ProfileUser->mname = $Request->input('mname');
    $ProfileUser->lname = $Request->input('lname');
    $ProfileUser->homeaddress = $Request->input('homeaddr');
    $ProfileUser->mobilenum = $Request->input('mobilenum');
    $ProfileUser->accounttype = $Request->input('typeAcc');
    $ProfileUser->image1 = $Request->input('img1');  

    $ProfileUser->save();

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

but then i also have this modification in make:auth i made and added columns
this is my problem here since the function is using an array instead of the Request.

```
protected function create(array $data) <-- this is the Error
{        

    if($data->hasFile('image1')) { <-- from here to:

        $file = $data->file('image1');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Get Image Ext.
        $filename = time() . "." . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/employee/', $filename);

    } else {
        return $request;
    }                             <-- here this function

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['fname'] . " " . $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'mname' => $data['mname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'homeaddress' =>  $data['homeaddr'],
        'mobilenum' => $data['mobilenum'],
        'accounttype' => $data['typeAcc'],
        'image1' => $data['image1']         
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

if i commend out the file validation the create function work fine and is able to save to database but then i need the image to be move on the 1st function it works perfect but in the 2nd using a parameter array doesn't i know i have maybe a wrong syntax which i ask for now how. and if it's ok can you guys explain a bit about the difference between Request vs Array? that i may able also to understand both

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy and paste the actual error message you're seeing. And please try to use more punctuation and clear sentences - your question is unfortunately very difficult to read.

Comment: done editing my question above sir how is it. please do not block this question cause i want to learn on this question

Answer (score 0):

The $Request variable contains an object from the Laravel Request class (Illuminate \ Http \ Request).  [Read more about here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

An Array is a PHP data structure. [Read about arrays in PHP here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

To get all request's data as an array, you can call the method all() on the request object. It will give you an associative array.

```
$request->all();
```

Comment: yes but the thing is i was modifying the register form adding up a profile pic. Which then lead me to this problem and it's default code is (protected function create(array $data)). It uses an array and i add a new parameter beside it making it (protected function create(array $data, Request $request)). Also add up the params before the function which could generate a different error pointing to two argument paramater